# Python reading from non ascii file

Tags: io

I have a text file which contains the following character:
**ÿ**

When I try and read the file in I've tried both:

```
with open (file, "r") as myfile:
```

AND

```
with codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
```

with success. However when I try to read the file in as a string using:

```
file_string=myfile.read()
```

OR

```
file_string=myfile.readLine()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 11889: invalid start byte
```

Ideally I want it to ignore the character or subsitute it with '' or whitespace

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. Just use python2 instead of python3. I still can't seem to get it to work in python3 though